# node.js - understanding export behavior of a variable reference

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could someone help me understand the behavior of node.js export.* variable reference in below scenario?

**ConfigIndex.js**

```
GLOBAL.app_configs = require('./myconfigs.json');

exports.port = GLOBAL.app_configs.port;

exports.updateConfig = function(newconfigJSONObject, callback)
{
  GLOBAL.app_configs = newconfigJSONObject;
  callback("update complete");
});
```

**myconfigs.json**

```
{
  "port": 443
}
```

**app.js**

```
var config = require('./ConfigIndex.js');

console.log(config.port); //PRINTS the value 443

config.updateConfig ({"port": 9999}, function(resOut) {
    console.log(config.port); //PRINTS the value 443 again but I expected 9999
});
```

**--Question--**

When running app.js config.port outputs 443 but after calling config.updateConfig function, config.port still prints 443 when I am expecting the value 9999.

Could someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
exports.port = GLOBAL.app_configs.port;
```

because `.port` is just a number, `exports.port` just contains a copy of that number.  It no longer has any connection to `GLOBAL.app_configs.port` in any way so no matter what you change `GLOBAL.app_configs.port` to, it has no influence at all on the completely separate variable `exports.port`.

Perhaps this might make it a little more obvious:

```
var x = 3;       // assign primitive value 3 to x
var y = x;       // copy the primitive value 3 from x to y
x = 4;           // assign primitive value 4 to x
console.log(x);  // shows 4
console.log(y);  // shows 3
```

In Javascript, primitive values like numbers are assigned by value upon assignment and become separate values (you can think of it like copying the value into the new variable).

---

Objects in Javascript are assigned by pointer which may have led you to think it might have the behavior you were expecting, but not for primitives like a number.

So, the only way to have a value that is changed in the way you were showing is to have a property embedded in an object and retain a reference to the object in your variable.  Then, when someone changes the property in that object and you then reference that property, you will see the changed value.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is [pass/assign by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value). If you have

```
var foo = 42;
var bar = foo;
```

then assigning a new value to `foo`, e.g.

```
foo = 21;
```

will **not** magically update `bar`.

That's how JavaScript works and has nothing to do with `exports` or Node.

---

In order to update `exports.port` you have to assign to it.